# Rubymineで、cmd + / を押してのコメントアウト時、先頭にスペースを入れたい

Tags: ruby, intellij-idea, rubymine

他のエディタでは当たり前のことなのですが、、

```rb
puts "Hello World!"
```

という行でcmd + / を押すと、

```rb
#puts "Hello World!"
```

となり、#の後に半角スペースが入りません。
細かいことですがコーディング規約に反するので、このようにスペースを入れるようにしたいのです。

```rb
# puts "Hello World!"
```

方法をご教授頂けると幸いです。よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a known problem  (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-25454) and it should be fine starting from 2019.3.2 Preview (2019.3.2 RC is available at https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/RUBYDEV/Early+Access+Program)

Google Translate -> Japanese:

それは既知の問題です https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-25454

2019.3.2 Preview (2019.3.2 RCは https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/RUBYDEV/Early+Access+Program で利用可能です) からは問題ないはずです

Comment: It is recommended to write answers with Japanese on this site(ja.stackoverflow.com). Could you please rewrite your answer in Japanese if possible ?

Comment: Unfortunately my knowledge of this language is poor, but I can add a Google translation if it's acceptable

Comment: Thanks for your response. That would be helpful.

Comment: Great! I installed the latest version, and it works as I wish. Thank you for your answer in spite of the Japanese question.